# Apache portable runtime tutorials?

Tags: c, portability

My platform is gcc 4.4.3, C89, on Ubuntu 10.4.

I am looking for some tutorials or ebooks for installing and using the Apache portable runtime.

So far, I have only found the links below. I was looking for something with more information. A book text book that explains everything from installing apr, to linking and compiling with your application.

http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/index.html

http://dev.ariel-networks.com/apr/apr-tutorial/html/apr-tutorial.html#toc1

Many thanks for any advice,

Comment: For installation, check out this tutorial: http://www.techsww.com/tutorials/libraries/apr/installation/installing_apache_portable_runtime_library_on_ubuntu_linux.php

Comment: Great question, I found out about APR via SVN, these kind of cross platform C libs are great. If you don't already know about it, take a look at http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/ which is a lot more popular.

Comment: One of the founders wrote up [an introduction in Linux Magazine](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/154/) which has some tips.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are truly not so many ressources out there.
Here a few hopefully helpfull ones:

- A [short installation tutorial](http://www.techsww.com/tutorials/libraries/apr/installation/installing_apache_portable_runtime_library_on_ubuntu_linux.php)
  (guess you already know this).
- [Writing portable C Code using
  APR](http://people.apache.org/~rooneg/talks/portable-c-with-apr/apr.html) (short slide show)
- Chapter 3 of [the book "The Apache Modules Book: Application Development with Apache"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132409674) refers to
  APR, first part of it containing chapter 3 can be downloaded [here](http://www.51cnnet.net/files/1790-the-apache-modules-book-application-development-with-apache).
- A [page with some links](http://www.servinghistory.com/topics/Apache_Portable_Runtime) to
  further ressources related to APR

Comment: Amusing that the best tutorial is from an SVN developer. The only reason and project I know that actually uses it :P

Comment: The Apache httpd web server project uses APR extensively.

Comment: @Thariama, Who else uses APR other than apache httpd?

Comment: @Pacerier, APR is a dependency of the Tomcat Native Library from... Apache :)